# Convert database string to date in sql & laravel

Tags: php, laravel, string, date

I have made a problem here. I have stored date into the database in a string format but now I am finding records on the basis of dates. and it is not working. What is the solution to this problem

**datatype : varchar** |
**data : eg. 01-10-2002**

```
$current_month_balance =
      tbl_wallet_detail::
      whereMonth('start_date', date('m'))
      ->whereYear('start_date', date('Y'))
      ->get();
```

Comment: Add proper date columns, update the new column(s) from the old columns using `STR_TO_DATE()`, remove the old columns, reame the new columns to be the old column names, check all the code that loaded these string dates and make sure it is now loading a date properly

Comment: Sir, without changing the datatype is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to change database type of that column to date, and i would say that if possible that would be the correct solution.

If this is not possible, you could try something like this (based on the date format that you provided):

```
$current_month_balance =
  tbl_wallet_detail::
  whereMonth(DB::raw("STR_TO_DATE(start_date, '%d-%m-%Y')"), date('m'))
  ->whereYear(DB::raw("STR_TO_DATE(start_date, '%d-%m-%Y')"), date('Y'))
  ->get();
```

This will search a raw DB statement instead of an attribute.
Tested on MySQL